# Is Poly-N= S ? $\hspace{1cm}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know poly-**X** property i.e. there exist a subnormal series of finite length such that all factors lies in class **X**.

Now suppose **X** is the class of nilpotenet group, i.e. **N**, then is Poly-**N**= **S**, where **S** is the class of soluble groups.

Poly-**A=S** where **A** is abelian groups class is the definition of soluble groups. But In a book "Group and Ring Theoretic Properties of Polycyclic Groups" , Wehrfritz writes, Poly-**N=S** and Poly-**S=S**. See the following image-

[image]

May be it should have been $P$**A=A** and $P$**N=N** where I have underlined?

Comment: You have underlined "For example" so I don't really understand your question. As far as I can see, everything that Wehrfriz has written is correct. Poly-A = S and Poly-N = S are both correct. Can you say exactly what you think is wrong?

Comment: When he says $P$N=S, in the line that follows red underline, what does he mean?

Comment: $S \subseteq P$N is OK, but for other containment, I have doubt.

Comment: @DerekHolt $1 \unlhd D_8 \unlhd D_8 \rtimes G$ is a subnormal series where factors are nilpotent, so according to $PN=S$ for every group $G$, $D_8 \rtimes G$ should be solvable, but it cannot be. What I am missing here?

Comment: I don't know what you are missing. How can I tell what you are missing? If $G$ is nilpotent then $D_8 \rtimes G$ is solvable. The statement Poly-N=S is correct. If you agree that Poly-S=S then this is clear because Poly-N $\subseteq$ Poly-S$.

Comment: Let $G \in$ Poly-N , now if Poly-N $\subseteq S$, it means $G$ is also solvable and that requires $G$ to have a subnormal series with abelian factors (definition of solvable), but definition of Poly-N only tells us that it has a series with  nilpotent factors , and guarantees nothing about factors being abelian.

Comment: Nilpotent groups have subnormal series with abelian factors.